# Jwplayer does not appear on android mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, html, ionic-framework, jwplayer

I am working on developing my own android app using ionic framework. This app supposed to play a video using jwplayer within the app by playing a video from external host (i.e YouTube). It works fine on browser using

```
ionic serve
```

[jwplayer on browser (chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll4uc.png)

but when I trying run it on my connected android device by command

```
ionic run android
```

the jwplayer does not show up

[jwplayer on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpks6.png)

I think its supposed to work as ionic framework usinghtml and javascript programming.

Is there anyway I can embed jwplayer using ionic framework and make it work on android devices?

```html
<html>
<head>

    <script src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script>jwplayer.key="1eI53zuaZKQ3WuMYKSyIpgTd9+hP/HOTsG+Dww==";</script>
  
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Stream here</h2>

            <div id="player">Loading the player...</div>            

            <script type="text/javascript">
                        var playerInstance = jwplayer("player");
                        playerInstance.setup({
                        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPVEVbBkrc8",
                        
                        width: 450,
                        height: 225,
                        });
            </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JW Player doesn't support running jwplayer.js in a WebView, which is likely the reason you're getting errors. The mobile SDKs are now included in the free JW Player license, though, so I would recommend trying that out. You can access the Android SDK under "Downloads" in your [JW Player Dashboard](https://dashboard.jwplayer.com), and there's documentation on the [JW Player Developer Site](https://developer.jwplayer.com/android-sdk/).